# Issue while starting Cassandra 3.11.2 due to space in installation path

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

We recently upgraded from Cassandra version 3.11 to 3.11.2 and we are facing an issue in starting Cassandra. We have a space in our path where we install Cassandra like :

C:\Program Files\XYZ Software\cassandra

which gives me the following error

Error: Could not find or load main class Files\XYZ

Any pointers at resolving this ?

Comment: Move Cassandra to another place, where there is no space in path? I once checked the startup scripts, and the correct handling of paths weren't everywhere...

Comment: In our product cassandra gets installed into Program Files as default path , is there no way around this ?

Comment: the only way to do it is to patch all windows scripts in Cassandra installation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like there is a bug in cassandra`s cassandra-env.ps1 script.
Open cassandra-env.ps1 present under cassandra_home/conf and check line number 380 where it is setting up JVM_OPTS.

This trick worked for me when I replace line here
From:
    $env:JVM_OPTS = "$env:JVM_OPTS -XX:CompileCommandFile=$env:CASSANDRA_CONF\hotspot_compiler"

To:
    $env:JVM_OPTS = "$env:JVM_OPTS -XX:CompileCommandFile=""$env:CASSANDRA_CONF\hotspot_compiler"""

At other places this case was well handled.

Below is the issue created to get this fix in the future releases.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-14418

Comment: Thanks spdev for the help.